# docker pull image using several tags

Tags: docker, containers

I have an image in AWS ECR with several tags. For example:

image name: myapp

tags: 1.0.1 , staging , latest

Now  I want to pull this docker image using the version number tag + environment tag.

I already have tried:

```
docker pull 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-west-100.amazonaws.com/myapp:1.0.1:staging
```

but I get the error:

> invalid reference format

Do you know if this is possible somehow?

Remark: using only 1 tag it's working. For example: myapp:1.0.1

Comment: you cant create tags in that way, but you can create multiple tags from a image.

Comment: you can't specify more than one tag at a time... you will have to have separate pull calls for each tag

Comment: Try using ' - ' instead of ' : ' like: 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-west-100.amazonaws.com/myapp:1.0.1-staging

Comment: Why do you need to pull all the tags at once? Do you need every tag or just one? Do you need to have them all pulled simultaneously or can it happen serially?

Comment: Sergiu - myapp:1.0.1-stag‌​ing not working ;
Leonardo Cabré - I'm trying to do pull to image ;
user3012759 - ok. I thought that there is a way to do that ;
BMitch - I wanted to do this in one command and not in seperate commands ;
thank you all!!!

Comment: @dsaydon first you will have to build an image with that tag and then try to pull it :)

Comment: so what is difference between 1.0.1 image and staging image? or which one do you actually want to pull?

Comment: @dsaydon what is the use case for pulling multiple tags with a single command?

Comment: @BMitch , something old that I needed to do for cache stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/)

`--all-tags, -a     false   Download all tagged images in the repository`

so you can actually do following to get **ALL** tags:

`docker pull --all-tags 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-west-100.amazonaws.com/myapp`

If you do require just some tags it's sadly impossible at the moment, but for that you can just put it inside of a script or `&&` it or whatever else you like.